# In Sphinx, document attributes provided via __getattr__

Tags: python-sphinx

In Python's Sphinx, how do I document attributes that are available thanks to `__getattr__`?

I have an instance of some config manager that allows accessing any section of the configuration via attribute that matches a section name i.e. `config_manager.<section_name>`.

For now I document this inside .rst file (but would prefer in code) with something like this:

```
.. autoclass:: ConfigManager
    :members:
    :var .<section_name>: Access any section of the configuration by its name.
```

but this doesn't appear too prominently in the docs, even though providing this kind of access is one of the main purposes of that class.

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't appear too prominently"? Does anything appear at all?

Comment: Methods appear what I would call prominently. This thing I have annotated with `:var` appears just under class description as "Variables: bullet list". I wanted them to appear as methods too.

Comment: Why do you want them to appear "as methods"? They are not methods. Am I missing something?

Comment: They are effectively public members. My mistake, I don't want them to appear *as* methods, just *like* methods (or properties, or public attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.. attribute::` directive, like this:

```
.. autoclass:: ConfigManager
    :members:

    .. attribute:: <section_name>

       Access any section of the configuration by its name.
```

The attributes will appear before the methods (and presented like the methods) in the output.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks! It even works when I move it to the docstring of the class.